# Adding log4j1x and log4j2x dependency causes duplicate class error during maven build

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

I have to keep both the log4j versions so that ops can use as needed.

I have to use the below dependency

- for log4j1:  org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25
- for log4j2: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.14.1

I'm getting this error:

> [WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.14.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25]:
> [WARNING]   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
> [WARNING]   org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder
> [WARNING]   org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder
> [WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in test classpath.
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.2.1:check (default) on project server: Found duplicate classes/resources! -> [Help 1]

Questions:

1. Is there any way to just remove these classes from log4j-slf4j-impl while mvn build?
2. Any other way to fix it?

Note: 1st time using SOF, please reply if further info required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to analyze you pom by `mvn dependency:tree` and check which is the artifact which depends on **log4j1**, then add to it the exclusion of the offending **log4j1** like follow:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: not using any spring framework dependencies.  using the below dependencies directly. `        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>      
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
            </dependency>`